# create index for select query with multiple OR conditions and AND conditions

Tags: mysql, indexing, composite-index, or-condition

I have a query like the one shown below:

```
select count(test.id) from table1 
   inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
   where    (table2.email = 'test@gmail.com' 
   OR (table2.phone1 IS NOT NULL AND table2.phone1 in ('123456')) 
   OR (table2.phone2 IS NOT NULL AND table2.phone2 in ('1234456'))) 
   AND table2.id <> 1234 
   AND table2.created_at >= '2015-10-10' 
   AND table2.status NOT IN ('test') 
   AND table2.is_test = 'No';
```

I have an index on  table2.email, table2.phone1, table2.phone2, table2.created_at. These are all single indexed and not composite indexes. As far as I know, a composite index on (table2.email, table2.phone1, table2.phone2) would not work because the conditions are OR conditions.
I created a composite index on (table2.id, table2.created_at, table2.status, table2.is_test) but I got the same result in the explain query.
The explain query is shown below

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys key     key_len ref rows Extra
 1  SIMPLE     table2   range   PRIMARY,     created_at  8        293  Using where
                                created_at,
                                email,
                                phone1,
                                phone2, 
                                com_index       
  1   SIMPLE    table1  eq_ref  PRIMARY       PRIMARY    4    id   1  Using index
```

Here com_index is the composite index I created. How can I create an index to speed this query up. It looks like from the explain result, the key selected for the query is created_at. Is there a way I can create a composite index for table 2?
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
explain for production on this query:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                                | key     | key_len | ref                  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | l0_   | range  | PRIMARY,created_at,email,day_phone,eve_phone | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL                 | 942156 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | m1_   | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                      | PRIMARY | 4       | lead_platform.l0_.id |      1 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------+--------+-------------+
```

Comment: You've got a bunch of constant conditions on `table2`, so you might get better results by joining on a materialized query which has pre-filtered candidates. Though, honestly, I'm not seeing why this query is particularly inefficient given the match size (293x1 rows).

Comment: @bishop  this is in local environment, not in production. In production the table2 is much larger.

Comment: Ah. Can you please show an `EXPLAIN` on your production data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Genrally, MySQL can't use an index on 3 possible columns (email, phone1, phone2).

I suspect the rest of your conditions are not very specific and will not give great results on your production database (meaning, most of the items are not "Test" etc.).

Optimizing a query with an `OR` statement across multiple columns is tricky.

This [article](http://www.techfounder.net/2008/10/15/optimizing-or-union-operations-in-mysql/) shows that splitting such a query to multiple queries with `UNION` can be much faster. In your case, it would be 3 queries combined, with no OR statements. 
This way MySQL can perform an index merge - using the indexes on `email`, `phone1` and `phone2`.

Test it and let me know if it's faster on real data.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(t.id)) FROM (
    SELECT test.id FROM table1 
       INNER JOIN table2 on table1.id = table2.id
       WHERE table2.email = 'test@gmail.com' 
       AND table2.id <> 1234 
       AND table2.created_at >= '2015-10-10' 
       AND table2.status NOT IN ('test') 
       AND table2.is_test = 'No'

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT test.id FROM table1 
       INNER JOIN table2 on table1.id = table2.id
       WHERE table2.phone1 IS NOT NULL AND table2.phone1 in ('123456')
       AND table2.id <> 1234 
       AND table2.created_at >= '2015-10-10' 
       AND table2.status NOT IN ('test') 
       AND table2.is_test = 'No'

    UNION ALL   

    SELECT test.id FROM table1 
       INNER JOIN table2 on table1.id = table2.id
       WHERE table2.phone2 IS NOT NULL AND table2.phone2 in ('1234456')
       AND table2.id <> 1234 
       AND table2.created_at >= '2015-10-10' 
       AND table2.status NOT IN ('test') 
       AND table2.is_test = 'No') AS t
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not splay an array of things across columns.  In this case, have a table of phone numbers with links back to `table1`.  That table would have 0, 1, 2, or even more numbers for a given table1 type person.  Then no `OR` or `UNION` is needed.  Instead a `JOIN` is needed.

You have `status` and `is_test`; these seem redundant.  Having lots of flags is not helpful; can these be combined?

I don't understand doing a lookup by `email OR phone`.  Seems like you would have one or the other value, not both.  In that case, construct the `WHERE` clause (and `JOIN`), then there won't be an `OR` for this.

After all that, have `INDEX(phone)` in the new table and `INDEX(email)` in `table1`.  Since email and phone are probably very selective, I would not add `status`, etc, to the indexes.